# Read all files in .zip archive in python

Tags: python, zip

I'm trying to read all files in a `.zip` archive named `data1.zip` using the `glob()` method.

```
import glob
from zipfile import ZipFile

archive = ZipFile('data1.zip','r')
files = archive.read(glob.glob('*.jpg'))
```

Error Message:

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'list'
```

The solution to the problem I'm using is:

```
files = [archive.read(str(i+1)+'.jpg') for i in range(100)]
```

This is bad because I'm assuming my files are named `1.jpg`, `2.jpg`, etc.

Is there a better way using python best practices to do this? Doesn't need to be necessarily using `glob()`

Comment: You could use [namelist](https://docs.python.org/2/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) and then filter out all of the `jpg` files

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`glob` doesn't look inside your archive, it'll just give you a list of `jpg` files in your current working directory.

`ZipFile` already has methods for returning information about the files in the archive: `namelist` returns names, and `infolist` returns `ZipInfo` objects which include metadata as well.

Are you just looking for:

```
archive = ZipFile('data1.zip', 'r')
files = archive.namelist()
```

Or if you only want `.jpg` files:

```
files = [name for name in archive.namelist() if name.endswith('.jpg')]
```

Or if you want to read all the contents of each file:

```
files = [archive.read(name) for name in archive.namelist()]
```

Although I'd probably rather make a dict mapping names to contents:

```
files = {name: archive.read(name) for name in archive.namelist()}
```

That way you can access contents like so:

```
files['1.jpg']
```

Or get a list of the files presents using `files.keys()`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to glob the contents of a zip archive, so I extract into a temp dir and glob that.

```py
import os
import glob
import zipfile
import tempfile

with tempfile.TemporaryDirectory() as tempdir:
    # extract zip to temporary directory to perform glob operations on it
    with zipfile.ZipFile(your_zip_file) as zf:
        zf.extractall(str(tempdir))

    # apply any glob statement here
    newest_one = max(glob.glob(f"{tempdir}/**/*", recursive=True), key=os.path.getctime)
```